# What is the Best Software for Create Report for .Net Application?

Tags: crystal-reports

I want design and use reports for my .NET windows application. I use Crystal Reports to design reports, but Crystal Reports is very slow when my report shows.

What is the best software to design and view reports for .NET application?

I'm looking for design-time software and not runtime reporting tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that your report displays slowly has nothing to do with the ease of use, at design or runtime, of a reporting tool.

You should look at what indexes are present and whether you can simplify the underlying data query.

The 'best' anything depends somewhat on your requirements.

That all said, I personally prefer Active Reports over Crystal.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at [Windward Reports](http://www.windwardreports.com/) (I'm the CTO at Windward). With Windward you design the reports in Microsoft Word, Excel, or PowerPoint so layout/formatting is very fast & easy. And because you can place the tags for the data anywhere, it gives you the ability to do things that Crystal, SSRS, etc. find difficulty to impossible.

As to performance issues, there are some good general rules of thumb at [How to Turbo-Charge your Report Speed](http://www.sql-reports.net/2011/02/how-to-turbo-charge-your-report-speed.html).

thanks - dave